# Python socket error: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly

Tags: python, sockets

I start to build a simple client - server chat room today and I am new to Python and network connection. I made a simple code on server something like this:

```
HOST = socket.gethostname()
PORT = 21238
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((HOST, PORT))
```

On the client:

```
HOST = socket.gethostbyaddr('54.201.33.XX') #54.201.33.XX is my EC2 public IP
PORT = 21237
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((HOST, PORT))
```

I have already running my server code on server and when I am trying to run client code on my PC. I got the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly
```

I have found some sample codes but nealy all of them are using local host. Thank you for your helps.

/////

Based on @Jon S.'s answer. My client code should be

```
HOST = '54.201.33.XX'
```

But still time out to connect to server. I am sure my ip is correct.

Comment: See the top answer below. [Here is a good how to about socket programming in python](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html), you are missing the socket.listen command on your server.

Comment: I have listen method but did not show here. The problem now is now like  EC2 setting. I found, server end hostname is my private IP by printing out hostname however on client end I use pubic IP. Do you know what should I do some operations on EC2?

Comment: I am not sure about EC2 and firewalls, do you know if that port is open. The easiest way to test is setup a simple server and see if you can access it. e.g. `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 21237` and go to http://54.201.33.XX:21237 and see if you can access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

1. On server, the HOST = socket.gethostname(); On client, the HOST = '54.201.33.XX', which is your server ip address
2. In EC2, the default security setting is only open ssh. You should open the Port you have used in your codes. The operations are following:

   2.1 Enter AWS console and enter EC2

   2.2 Find Security Group on the left under NETWORK & SECURITY

   2.3 Click your current security group (For me, it is not the default one) and open Inbound  on the below information

   2.4 Choose Custom TCP rule and enter your Port range (21237 in my pasted code) and click on add Rules

   2.5 DO NOT forget to press button "Apply Rule Changes"!!!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is

```
HOST = socket.gethostbyaddr('54.201.33.XX')
```

in your second example. gethostbyaddr returns a tuple, containing (hostname, a list of aliases, ip addresses). connect expects a string as the first element of the tuple that specifies the address and port to connect to.

You can change this to

```
HOST = '54.201.33.XX'
```

and it should work.

Comment: Hi Jon, Thank you for your reply. I have tried and it is not working? I have got my IP address from EC2 instance public IP. Both codes on server and client part are attached. Do you know what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: As @Pykler points out, the server code you have doesn't call listen or accept.

Also, what do you mean by "it is not working"? Is it throwing an error? Timing out? Which part sees an error, client or server?

Comment: In server end, the codes are still: HOST = socket.gethostname().
In client end, the codes are: HOST = '54.201.33.XX'
The problem is client end time out because it can not find host.
I checked my ip in EC2. I found, server end hostname is my private IP by printing out hostname and client end I use pubic IP. Do you know how should I change my private ip to public one in codes or should I do some operations on EC2? Thank you.